# how to restore default system variables or a shoot of the list of sys. variables on win 10

Tags: variables, path

I deleted some system environment variables accidentally and I dont know which ones there are, for that am requesting for a shoot of the variables or how to restore to default. your responses will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Reinstall the operating system.

Comment: i understand. but no thank you. i appreciate your response. any other options?